# Avoid downloading a file again if it hasn't changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I need to download an XML file, using HTTP protocol, to use it locally on my iPhone app. Occasionally this file will be updated on the server, but not very often.

How do I compare the already downloaded file that is already in the Documents folder, with the one on the server, just downloading it if the content has been updated on the server?

Comment: By name. Or by date would be efficient too?

Comment: What protocol are you using to download the file?  HTTP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first time you download the file, save the date from the Last-Modified header of the response.  You can pull it out of the `NSHTTPURLResponse` object.

On subsequent runs, put that date in the `If-Modified-Since` header of the `NSURLRequest`.  If the file on the server hasn't changed, the `statusCode` of the `NSHTTPURLResponse` should be 304 (which means “Not Modified”) and the body of the response should be empty.

Comment: Beautiful.  Much more efficient than my solution.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'll try that. Can I verify it not only by date, but also including the time?

Comment: An HTTP date includes the time, and is in a very specific format.  The headers are defined in [section 14 of the HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).  The date format is defined in [section 3.3.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1).

Comment: It will probably be easiest for you to just treat the date as an opaque string that you copy out of the `Last-Modified` header, save in `NSUserDefaults`, and copy into the `If-Modified-Since` header, without trying to parse it.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot, I'll try it and let you know the results!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to traverse the documents directory to look for a specifically named file, use NSFileManager's `-fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory` and compare it to the name of the downloaded file (`-suggestedFilename` as long as you are using NSURLResponse) with `-isEqualToString`.

If you need to get a revision date, use NSFileManager's `-attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` in conjunction with the key NSFileModificationDate.

Comment: The file name would be the same, but if the contant is the same too? Will I have to download it again, with both files being exactly the same?

Comment: Checking their contents would involve downloading it to a temp directory and checking.  I've posted the way to get a modification date; though my knowledge of HTTP requests is quite limited.  Is there a way to get the modification date from the HTTP header?