# JSON Background Processing and Local Notification

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I am writing a program to pull some JSON data off of a 3rd party website.  What I would like to happen is run my method to pull the data, and cycle through the data finding seeing if there is a newer date then the last time the system pulled it.  If there is, I want to send out a local notification that something was "Found".  I expect if there is new data to be there every 5 min, but I would like the users to schedule a time interval from 5 min to once a day.  There is more I would like to check on but this is where I want to start.

I don't know where to begin, any help will be appreciated.
I am building this project in SWIFT on Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the following

1. For url fetching (For you json) - [NSURLSession tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c)
2. Look at ETAG, Last-Modified headers to check if JSON file is modified at server. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068868/avoid-downloading-a-file-again-if-it-hasnt-changed)
3. NSTimer for for your timing requirements. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift)
4. For notifications: Use NSNotification. [Refer this](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/)